# 7zip: Extract archive(s) which take up >= 50% of HDD

Tags: 7-zip, rar

How can you use 7zip to extract a collection of .rar files which if extracted normally would surpass the size of your HDD?

Say your HDD was 10GB, if you had a zip archive of 5GB, how could you extract the contents of the archive without going over the 10GB limit? Can you configure 7zip to delete each part upon extraction of its contents?

Comment: @Sickest In the extraction process, isn't each archive component (archiveX.rar) extracted serially, meaning it can be deleted following extraction?

Comment: Do you see an option in 7zip that does this? 2ndly have you tried to just do this? Delete 1 file out of the rar while its extracting, please report back what happens.

Comment: i'm 99.9% sure you can't, but i don't see why you cant just look for the option yourself, or test your theory that you can delete a .rar file while its extracting. what could go wrong?

Comment: I have tried to find a switch which does do this but haven't found one. I'll have a go at deleting after extracting.

Comment: If the HDD capacity is falling shot only by a small margin; say 2-4 GB; and you have enough RAM, you can create RAm disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each of the *elements* of the archive is smaller than the free space, one could extract the  each file indivdually, process them and then remove them. Something like this:

`foo.7z` contains 10 files of arbitrary size. List, extract, delete:

```
$ 7za l ../foo.7z
   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2014-01-20 02:11:01 ....A        16885       189065  file.0
2014-01-20 02:11:01 ....A        40122               file.1
[...]

$ 7za l ../foo.7z | awk '/^2014/ {print $NF}' | while read a; do
    7za x ../foo.7z $a > /dev/null
    do-something-with $a
    rm -f $a
done
```

If there's only one big file in the archive, one could try to extract to stdout and then play games with `dd`:

```
 7za a archive.7z one-big-file
 7za x -so archive.7z 2>/dev/null | dd bs=1M count=100 2>/dev/null > part.1
 7za x -so archive.7z 2>/dev/null | dd bs=1M count=100 skip=100 2>/dev/null > part.2
 7za x -so archive.7z 2>/dev/null | dd bs=1M count=100 skip=200 2>/dev/null > part.3
 [...]
```

...and so on, until `dd` can't skip no more (and `part.N` will be empty).

Answer (score 0):

The most sensible way is to buy /borrow another Hard drive (internal or external). Then, you can extract all and do what ever you need to (such as delete the original zip).

Alternatively, you can do this manually, in 7-ZIP there is the option to delete. So, you could open 7-ZIP, drag file(s) to the local computer and then delete it from the original compressed archive.